# How to generate certificate (public key) from just the csr?

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, certificate

I have a key and csr generated and want to use the csr to generate certificates. GoDaddy has a provision wherein the csr can be uploaded for the cert to be generated and am wondering what equivalent openssl command is run to convert csr to cert?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

The openssl commmand is:

```
openssl x509 -signkey GoDaddy.key -in domain.csr -req -days 365 -out domain.crt
```

Note that **it is not a conversion** of the csr into a certificate, it is a generation of a certificate from a csr and a private key. The key is always needed. The fact that you don't send your key to GoDaddy is because it's **YOUR** private key (as pointed out in the comments) and because they sign your certificate with their own private key. That's what makes it *special*. That's why they are paid for.

In this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/openssl-essentials-working-with-ssl-certificates-private-keys-and-csrs) you can find some useful openssl commands that may help you in the future.

Comment: The fact that you don't send your public key to Godaddy is because it's already in the CSR; the fact that you don't send them your private key is because it's private; and the fact that they sign it with their private key is because that's what you're paying them to do.

Comment: Exactly added @EJP. I was exemplifying why they don't need a private key when one sends them the CSR and when one generates his own he needs to specify one. Already added some info to the answer addressing your point.